# Navbar small resolution changing to two rows

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

My navbar keeps transforming to two rows when I collapse it. I tried correcting it with the CSS I shall post after the navbar code. That, unfortunately, completely f****d my dropdown menu over and broke it into buttons smaller than the actual menu button. I'm new to html/css, I just learned it over the last four days. I also tried another method with the class nowarp in the main navbar class, that also produced lackluster results.

Note: If I can do it without all the complicated CSS I was attempting and learned half from another question, I would really appreciate it.

```
<!-- Navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <!-- Navigation Bar Menu Button for Smaller Resolutions -->
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#example-nav-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-inner">
                    <!-- Logo -->
                    <a class="brand visible-xs-inline" href="index.html"> <img id="cherry" src="img/cheery3.svg"></a>
                    <!-- Small Resolution Navigation Label -->
                    <div class="navbar-right visible-xs-inline">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li><a id="nav-label" href="#">Navigation <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- General Links to Other Pages -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="example-nav-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="visible-sm visible-md visible-lg"><a id="cherrybox" href="#"><img id="cherrytoo" src="img/cheery4.svg" alt=""></a></li>
                    <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="bitcoin/index.html">Bitcoin</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Broken CSS

```
/*Important Small Resolution Fixes Section!*/
.navbar-left {float: left !important;}

.navbar-right {float: right !important;}
@media(max-width:767px)
{
.navbar-right {margin-right:20px;}
.navbar-header:after 
{
clear: none;
}
.navbar-nav.navbar-right > li { float: left; }

.navbar-collapse:before {clear:both;}

.navbar-collapse {overflow-y: hidden;}
.navbar-collapse.in {overflow-y: visible;}

.navbar-collapse.in > ul {border-top: 1px double #101010;}
}
.navbar-brand {
font-size: 25px;
line-height: 10px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
}
.logo_tagline {
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 10px;
letter-spacing: 2px;
color:#bbb;
}
}
/*End Fixes for Small Resolution*/
```

Comment: how do you want your navbar to look like?

Comment: May be adding the whole content to  `margin:0 auto;position:relative` helps !

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you are after, but here's my best guess. For this I have just pretty much reverted your code back to the Bootstrap default navbar. I then replaced the 3 horizontal bars that make up the toggle button with the word 'Navigation' and an alternative glyphicon.

```
<!-- Navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <!-- Navigation Bar Menu Button for Smaller Resolutions -->
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#example-nav-collapse">
                  Navigation <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large"></span>
                </button>

            </div>
            <!-- General Links to Other Pages -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="example-nav-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="visible-sm visible-md visible-lg"><a id="cherrybox" href="#"><img id="cherrytoo" src="img/cheery4.svg" alt=""></a></li>
                    <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="bitcoin/index.html">Bitcoin</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

If this isn't what you were after please explain more clearly what you did want, maybe with mockups/pictures of the problem.